How can I grant permissions to a client that is not a User in Django?
I have a Django Rest Framework application that has been working well with OIDC auth and human interactions using django-oauth-toolkit.
Now I want to add a couple of service accounts so that some external automation can make some requests and create some objects. According to django-oauth-toolkit,

The Client Credential grant is suitable for machine-to-machine authentication.

So I've implemented this grant type and tested it out with the below script:
client_id='axXSSBVuvOyGVzh4PurvKaq5MHXMm7FtrHgDMi4u'
secret='hun***2'
credential="${client_id}:${secret}"
CREDENTIAL=$(printf '%s' "$credential" | base64)
export CREDENTIAL
(
set -x
r=$(
curl "http://[::1]:8080/o/token/" \
     -H "Authorization: Basic ${CREDENTIAL}" \
     -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     -X POST \
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
     -d 'user=2'
)
access_token=$(jq -r '.access_token' <<< "$r")
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" 'http://[::1]:8080/notify/riskimpacts/'
)

and the response is an HTTP 403:
{"detail":"You do not have permission to perform this action."}

It authenticates, but does not authorize any access to any views, because there is no user associated with these credentials. In fact, django-oauth-toolkit removes the user from the request even if there should be one, so there really cannot ever be a user associated with the access token created here.
Yet, all but the most open (practically anonymous) django-rest-framework permissions require a User.
Other descriptions of authz systems I have read about have the useful term "principal". A principal might be a User, but it could also be some other thing that interacts with the system and can have permissions and credentials.  Most of the descriptions of client credentials I've read…

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/
https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#client-credentials
https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/client-credentials/
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/06/node-api-oauth-client-credentials

…describe the flow as something like being on behalf of the service instead of a user. But that just means the service is a principal. So, presumably, we would want to grant some permission to the service-principal instead of the user-principal.
I think I must have misunderstood the point of the client credential grant, so, I have some questions:

Is a client credential grant a fitting approach to use for service-to-service authentication when you want two services to use a single shared secret?
…If so, in django-oauth-toolkit/django-rest-framework, must we then create a custom permission class (based on scope, perhaps?) so that a client credential can have access to object(s), or is there a native or default (but not Anonymous) way for a client credential to access an object?
…Otherwise, what is a use case for client credentials that helps to understand the difference, and what is an approach for service-to-service auth that makes more sense?


I don't really get why you think there is a user, by default request.user is the AnonymousUser, I don't see what is adding a (different) user on the request?

@willeM_VanOnsem I don't think there is a user. I think the user is always None with the client credentials flow. What did I say wrong to make you think I thought there was a user, so I can improve my question?

then the authentication_classes in the view(set) apparently can not authenticate the user. Beware that if you don't add that login is required, it will not say that you did not log in.

@willeM_VanOnsem they sure can't. There is no user, or only the AnonymousUser to authenticate. But it doesn't make sense to me to have a whole oauth2 flow dedicated to Anonymous auth, but advertised for service-to-service auth.
